# Chaining Observer RxJs

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am using Observables to implement a WebSocket service in my Angular program.  So far I have

```
    readwrite(commands: command[]) : Observable<response[]>{
        const observabe = new Observable((observer)=>{
            this.socket.subscribe((socket:WebSocket)=>{
                const id = this.uid++;
                //// Not Sure About This ////
                this.observerMap[id]={
                    next: next=>{
                        observer.next(next);
                        delete this.observerMap[id]; ////<---- What I want to Achieve
                    },
                    error: error=> observer.error(error),
                    complete: ()=>observer.complete()
                }
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({requestType:'ReadWrite', commands: commands, id: id}));
            });
        });
        return observable;
    }
```

Then in my `ws.onmessgae` I have

```
    {
        const result = JSON.parse(event.data);
        this.observerMap[result.id]?.next(result.commands);
    }
```

This seems to do what I want but Im not sure if there is a cleaner way to handle this.  I cannot do the cleanup of the `observableMap[]` in the `ws.onmessage` because other messages hold an observer across multiple messages.  I also only want to do the cleanup after the `.next()` of the Observable has been processed which led me to this solution.  Using `.pipe()` causes execution before the observer executes.

Is there a cleaner way to chain these operations together?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should utilize the complete function in the following way:

```
readwrite(commands: command[]) : Observable<response[]>{
    const observabe = new Observable((observer)=>{
        this.socket.subscribe((socket:WebSocket)=>{
            const id = this.uid++;
            this.observerMap[id]={
                next: next=>{
                    observer.next(next);
                },
                error: error=> observer.error(error),
                complete: ()=> { 
                   observer.complete()
                   delete this.observerMap[id];
                }
            }
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({requestType:'ReadWrite', commands: commands, id: id}));
        });
    });
    return observable;
}
```

then in `onmessage`:

```
{
    const result = JSON.parse(event.data);
    this.observerMap[result.id]?.next(result.commands);
    this.observerMap[result.id]?.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) is the perfect use case for this. The way that you are writing your `observerMap` is actually implementing a Subject. It is incredibly simple to use.

1. Declare your Subject in a service you want to:

```
export class MessageService {

    message$ = new Subject<any>;
    constructor() { }
  }
```

2. In your code where `onmessage` is needed, simply do a `.next()` every time you receive a new message:

```
  {
        const result = JSON.parse(event.data);
        this.messageService.message$.next(result.commands);
  }
```

3. In your component just subscribe to it:

```
{
    this.messageService.message$.subsrcibe(console.log)
}
```